# How to refer DOM elements ID using "a href" inside views - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, href

I have tried to find some solution on google about this but couldn't get an exact answer.

I am trying to change tabs inside a view using below code:

```
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="{active: selectedTab === 'details'}"><a href ng-click="selectTab('details')">Details</a></li>
                <li class="{active: selectedTab === 'size'}"><a href ng-click="selectTab('size')">Size</a></li>
                <li class="{active: selectedTab === 'shipping'}"><a href ng-click="selectTab('shipping')">Shipping</a></li>
            </ul>
```

But whenever I am clicking on "Size" tab, the view redirects to some page. I mean URL changes 
**from** http://localhost:8080/abcd/index.html#/ **TO** http://localhost:8080/Final_Albatross/index.html#/size

Without view implementation, the click refers to id "size" and tab changes.

Definitely angular is treating this click as a new view call. Please help me out!!

My JS file:

```
mainAngular.controller('ProductDetailController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
$scope.prod_Id = $routeParams.prodId;
$scope.selectTab = function(tabName) {
    alert(tabName);
    $scope.selectedTab = tabName;
    alert($scope.selectedTab);
}
});
```

Although I have achieved it using "target="_self" but I want to do it in angular way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using anchor links in Angular require `target="_self"`.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#linktoroute">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anchor" target="_self">Anchor</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: even if making **target="_self"** , it still redirecting

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the jQuery, DOM way to handle that kind of problems. Use the angular way.

In AngularJS, the single point of truth is the model. The view (i.e. the HTML) is only a representation of that model, that changes automatically when the model changes.

So, you want a selected tab. Add that to the model:

```
$scope.selectedTab = 'details';
```

You want to be able to change which tab is selected. That is as simple as

```
$scope.selectTab = function(tabName) {
    $scope.selectedTab = tabName;
}
```

And you want the view to be reflect the model values:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="{active: selectedTab === 'details'}"><a href ng-click="selectTab('details'}">Details</a></li>
    <li class="{active: selectedTab === 'size'}"><a href ng-click="selectTab('size'}">Size</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have modified my code and the alerts are working fine but TABS are not changing. Anything m missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "tabs are not changing"? Do you mean the content of the tab, or the active CSS class of the tab? For the content of the tab, you also need something lik `<div ng-show="selectedTab === 'details'">content of the first tab</div>`